# move some of documents from one collection to another collection in Solr

Tags: solr

I have one collection and I want to move some of it's to another collection.

For example, I have a lot of documents in collection A and I want to move all 1 month older documents to collection B (these 1 month older documents should not be in collection A).

I using Python for this job.
How can I control the documents that are removed from Collection A transferred to Collection B? And the documentary has not gone away?

one solution that I know is:

- step one :

  I move documents to temp place (for example MySql)
- step Two :

  second code read all document from temp place, and then move to Collection B.
- step three :

  third code deletes from Collection A.

Do you know another solution?? how can I make sure documents are deleted from `Collection A`, only if `Collection B` has been inserted successfully

Answer (score 1):

To me this sounds a much better way (as long as all fields as stored):

1. use DIH with [SolrEntityProcessor](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#solrentityprocessor) to index the desired docs into the new collection
2. use delete by query to delete the docs

Of course you can verify the number of docs match by issues searches to the new collection and to the current one (instead of the delete)